# Getting array length inside map and filter

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am actually trying to get the length of the array inside my map, however the array belongs to the filter iterator and I am unable to retrieve the data. Can someone help me ?

```
 this.myArray.filter(flt =>
            UnixToDate(flt.end_date).date < new Date())
                .map(item => {
                   return (
                      <Text>array size: { ???? } - data: flt.data</Text>
                    )
                })
```

Comment: do you want the length of the original array or the length of the filtered array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?:

```
 this.myArray.filter(flt =>
            UnixToDate(flt.end_date).date < new Date())
                .map((item, idx, arr) => {
                   return (
                      <Text>array size: { arr.length } - data: flt.data</Text>
                    )
                })
```

Answer (score 4):

Map receives 3 arguments:

1. item
2. index
3. original array

> arr.map((curr, index, data) =>`${curr}-${index}-${data.length}`)

source: [Array map parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the third parameter is a reference to the array itself, from which you can get easily the length.

```
arr.map((value, index, arrayRef) => {
  console.log(arrayRef.length);
});
```

Also this is a Javascript related question. Not react.js nor react-native